# Why does D ignore conditions specified on a custom function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction, conditional

I define a function with a condition like so.

```
ClearAll[foo];
foo[expr_] /; FreeQ[expr, bar] := expr
```

Such that `foo[12]` returns `12`, and `foo[12 bar]` returns unevaluated as `foo[12 bar]`.

Why is it that when I take the derivative `D[foo[12 bar], x]` or `D[foo[12 bar], bar]` it acts as if the condition were not present, returning `0` and `12` respectively?

The expected and desired behaviour is that the derivative is not able to be evaluated. I consider the result that Mathematica gives to be *wrong*. My function does not have that output when that condition is not met, and that is therefore not a valid derivative.

I've found that additionally specifying that catch all `foo[_] := 0` means that `D` does take notice of the condition and uses that definition instead when appropriate, but without it the condition is ignored as shown above. Moving the condition to `foo[expr_] /; FreeQ[expr, bar] := expr` has no effect on the behaviour.

I guess that this line from the documentation may be relevant: "D returns generic results that may not account for discontinuities, cusps or other special points" Is my condition being treated as a special point? I don't want that, I just want it to behave like other functions that can't be evaluated for some input.

Comment: You are mixing programming constructs (`/;`) with mathematical constructs (`D`). In other words, the function you defined is not a function in the mathematical sense. It's a function in the programming sense. Trying to do math on it will lead to disaster sooner or later.

Comment: That's an interesting way to think about it @Szabolcs, but isn't that what many of the built in functions do? I'm thinking in particular of things like `Integrate`, which evaluate when they can and return unevaluated when they can't. The unevaluated forms are still valid for mathematical use. That's the style of function I was trying to create here.

Comment: `foo[12 bar]` is returning unevaluated and then `D` performs the symbolic differentiation on the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the calculation that *Mathematica* does internally, which is a chain rule:

```
D[foo[12 bar], bar] // Trace // TableForm
```

[image]

You can see that it needs to compute `foo'[12 bar]`, and the way it does this is to create a special internal indexed variable

```
System`Private`DerivativeX[1]
```

and computes the derivative with respect to that.  Because this doesn't have `bar` in it, it takes the derivative of the function

```
foo[System`Private`DerivativeX[1]]
```

which evaluates to

```
System`Private`DerivativeX[1]
```

whose derivative is just the function `1 &`, i.e. the constant-1 function. This is then evaluated at the original input `12*bar`, but of course `1` is returned, and so the final result is 12.

You can argue whether or not this is the right way to do things, but I think it is a *sensical* way to implement symbolic derivatives on nested functions internally. I don't really consider this a bug.

---

Now, to implement the desired behavior, we could short-circuit the evaluation of `D` by wrapping the expression in `HoldForm` at the appropriate step in the evaluation.  For instance, one could add the following `UpValue` to `foo`:

```
foo /: HoldPattern[D[foo[expr_], bar]] := HoldForm[D[foo[expr], bar]]
```

Then,

```
D[foo[12 bar], bar] // FullForm
(* HoldForm[D[foo[Times[12, bar]], bar]] *)
```

This might or might not be the desired form: it might be clunky to work with if you want to do further evaluations. However, there are some set of evaluation rules associated with `D`, and I don't think there is a way for *Mathematica* to return the unevaluated expression

```
D[foo[12*bar], bar]
```

Comment: Ah, this makes sense in terms of the implementation, but I can't see why it's not considered broken when the result is not mathematically sensible. Your explanation looks like the explanation of a bug, not a feature. In my use case, `foo` is meant to be a wrapper that only evaluates its contents under specific conditions. Is there a way to make it behave as expected (returning `D[foo[12 bar], x]` unevaluated), perhaps by a `Derivative[n_][foo][expr_] :=` style definition? Providing a work around as well as an explanation would make this an excellent answer.

Comment: @Sam. I've added one possible solution with some commentary. I'm not sure I could or would do anything else!

Comment: Thanks @march. I don't know whether the `HoldForm` approach will work for me because I do need to do further evaluation and manipulation, and as you say it's clunky. `Inactive[D]` might be a good alternative to `HoldForm` in some cases, although that's not very useful for me either. If anybody has any other ideas I'd like to see them, but this is an excellent answer to the question so I'm giving it the tick.

Comment: @Sam It might be worth holding off on accepting the answer in order to attract other answers.  There are pretty expert *Mathematica* users here, including many actual employees of Wolfram, and they might likely have a better response to both "Is it a bug?" and "What's a way to implement what I want?"  If the question has an accepted answer, it's less likely to attract more answers.

Comment: Fair enough @March, I've unaccepted for now. That's a very gracious thing for you to point out considering that the answer was yours.

Comment: @Sam. That's pretty standard practice around here, I think, and anyway I learn a lot from the other expert users' answers, especially answers for questions like this, so I will also benefit from other people coming here to answer.